# t-sql re-rank when group field changes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm stuck! I am trying to create a counter which starts at 1 again when group field changes:

This is what I am trying to get:

```
 ProdID  Date    counter
    123 1/1/2016    1
    123 1/2/2016    2
    123 1/3/2016    3
    123 1/4/2016    4
    456 1/1/2016    1
    456 1/2/2016    2
    789 1/1/2016    1
    789 1/2/2016    2
    789 1/3/2016    3
    789 1/4/2016    4
    789 1/5/2016    5
```

When I use `rank()` and over, doesn't reset when prodid changes?

Comment: show the query you used

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to select the data then this should give you those results:

```
SELECT
    ProdID,
    [Date],    -- A poor name for a column, since it's not only a reserved word, but also not at all descriptive
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY [Date]) AS counter
FROM
    My_Table
```

`PARTITION BY` tells SQL Server that you want the windows for the `ROW_NUMBER` windowed function to be partitioned by the `ProdID`. Imagine breaking up your data into groups by `ProdID`. The `ORDER BY` tells it to order the data within each window by the `Date` before applying the function.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Got stuck trying to use Rank(). Above works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
   SELECT  ProdId,Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY Date DESC) 
        AS Counter  from table
        order by Date ASC
```